# Memory management in phylogenetic tree pairwise distance calculations

Tags: r, memory-management, phylogeny

I have a metametabolite dendrogram (FTICR-MS data) and I'm measuring the pairwise branch lengths to create a null using randomized distribution.I'm using Bob Danczak's script [here](https://github.com/danczakre/Meta-Metabolome_Ecology/blob/master/FTICR_bNTI_create-nulls.R), which uses `cophenetic()` to calc the pairwise distances, then running a for loop to calculate the random distributions.  My input is a large list (`phylo`) of 46.1 MB.  Rightfully so I am receiving the error: `Error in dist.nodes(x) : tree too big` but I really need to calculate these distances.  What are some memory-managing techniques to circumvent this issue?  I'm certain it's the package and not my computer (8 cores, 64G RAM) though I'm never 100% confident when it comes to computers!

Comment: It would help to know where exactly the script is failing. How many metabolites are you working with? Is `cophenetic` the function throwing the error? Does it work if you exclude the `for` loop?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you let me know as well whenever you solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @AlperenTaciroglu, my solution was mostly unsatisfying.  Since I couldn't solve my problem from a computational standpoint, I took a step back and asked how I could pare down my input in a way where it could still answer my scientific questions.

Comment: With the help of @EmmanuelParadis from "ape" package, I started to calculate distances between nodes in a pairwise fashion. This effectively reduced my problem to a more manageable state. Leaving this here in case it is helpful: https://github.com/emmanuelparadis/ape/issues/64

Answer (score 0):

Another option I've found (in addition to taking a step back and re-thinking my phylogenetic tree) is to use iCAMP parallel computing:

```
library(iCAMP)
pd.big=iCAMP::pdist.big(tree = tree, wd=save.wd, nworker = nworker, memory.G = memory.G)
```